# ¿Replicar titulo de tabla en varias paginas de un PDF con XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xls

Hola: estoy generando una transformación de XML a PDF por medio de XSLT. El PDF de salida tiene varias páginas, lo que requiero es que los títulos de la tabla página 1 se repitan en la página 2, pág 3, etc.

Actualmente me esta generando así:

Página 1:

[image: página 1]

Página 2:

[image: Página 2]

Como se puede visualizar en la página 2 ya no me arrastra los títulos fijos de la página 1.
Por favor me pueden indicar ¿Qué debo tener en cuenta?, gracias.
Este es el XML:
Gracias por responder, este el XML:

```
      <Item>
      <NumeroLinea>1</NumeroLinea>
         <TablaCodigosItem>
            <CodigosItem>
               <TipoCodigo>Interna</TipoCodigo>
               <CodigoItem>01001</CodigoItem>
            </CodigosItem>
         </TablaCodigosItem>
         <IndicadorFacturacion>1</IndicadorFacturacion>
         <NombreItem>Cerveza Lager</NombreItem>
         <IndicadorBienoServicio>1</IndicadorBienoServicio>
         <CantidadItem>100</CantidadItem>
         <UnidadMedida>1</UnidadMedida>
         <GradosAlcohol>4.30</GradosAlcohol>
         <PrecioUnitarioItem>1550.15</PrecioUnitarioItem>
         <PrecioUnitarioReferencia>2000</PrecioUnitarioReferencia>
         <TipoImpuesto>005</TipoImpuesto>
         <DescuentoMonto>10</DescuentoMonto>
         <RecargoMonto>5</RecargoMonto>
         <MontoItem>135717.70</MontoItem>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <NumeroLinea>2</NumeroLinea>
         <TablaCodigosItem>
            <CodigosItem>
               <TipoCodigo>Interna</TipoCodigo>
               <CodigoItem>01002</CodigoItem>
            </CodigosItem>
         </TablaCodigosItem>
         <IndicadorFacturacion>4</IndicadorFacturacion>
         <NombreItem>Agua mineral</NombreItem>
         <IndicadorBienoServicio>1</IndicadorBienoServicio>
         <CantidadItem>200</CantidadItem>
         <UnidadMedida>34</UnidadMedida>
         <PrecioUnitarioItem>800</PrecioUnitarioItem>
         <TipoImpuesto>006</TipoImpuesto>
         <MontoItem>160632.58</MontoItem>
      </Item>
```

```
<!-- Body -->
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="8pt">
                    <!-- cuarta tabla con detalle de items (body) -->
                    <fo:table>

                        <fo:table-body>
                            
                           <fo:table-row>
                               <xsl:if test="position() > 14 and position() mod 14 = 1">
                                   <xsl:attribute name="break-before">page</xsl:attribute>
                               </xsl:if>
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-style="solid"
                                    padding-top="2px" padding-bottom="2px" padding-left="2px"
                                    padding-right="2px" background-color="LightGray"
                                    font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="'Cantidad'"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                               
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-style="solid"
                                    padding-top="2px" padding-bottom="2px" padding-left="2px"
                                    padding-right="2px" background-color="LightGray"
                                    font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="'Descripción'"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-style="solid"
                                    padding-top="2px" padding-bottom="2px" padding-left="2px"
                                    padding-right="2px" background-color="LightGray"
                                    font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="'Unidad de medida'"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
 </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Te faltó indicar cómo está el xsl que estás usando para transformar y el XML que usas como fuente. Puedes [edit] la pregunta para mostrar ésto (como texto, ojalá)

Comment: Gracias por responder, este el XML

Comment: ¿Has probado poner los "títulos" en `table-header` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_table-header) en lugar de `table-body`?